# More efficient way of calculating data from pandas dataframe (stock)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I was wondering if there is a more efficient/cleaner way of doing the following.  Say I have a dataframe that contains 2 columns, the percentage, (base on previous price) and the action, play/buy (1) or not play/sell (-1).  Its basically about stocks.

For simplicity, consider the example df:

```
Percent    Action
1.25       1
1.20       1
0.50       -1
0.75       1
```

I would like to generate the following.  I only care about the final money amount, I am just showing this table for reference.  Say we started with $100 and a state of not playing.  Thus we should get the money amount of:

```
Playing    Percent    Action    Money
No         1.25       1         $100
Yes        1.20       1         $120
Yes        0.50       -1        $60
No         0.75       1         $60
Yes        ...        ...       ...
```

The amount didnt change in the first row since we weren't playing yet.  Since the action is 1, we will play the next one.  The percentage went up 20%, thus we get $120.  The next action is still a 1, so we'll still be in the next one.  The percentage went down to 50% so we end up with $60.  Next action is -1, thus we will not play.  The percentage went down to 75%, but since we weren't playing, our money stayed the same.  And so on.

Currently, I have the code below.  It works fine, but just wondering if there is a more efficient way using numpy/pandas functions.  Mine basically iterates through each row and calculate the value.

```
playing = False
money = 10000

for index, row in df.iterrows():
   ## UPDATE MONEY IF PLAYING
   if index > 0 and playing == True:
      money = float(format(money*row['Percent'],'.2f'))

   ## BUY/SELL
   if row['Action'] == 1:
      if playing == False:
         playing = True         ## Buy, playing after this
      elif row['Action'] == -1:
         if playing == True:
            playing = False   ## Sell, not playing after this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
# decide whether to play based on action
df['Playing'] = df.Action.shift().eq(1)

# replace Percent for not playing row with 1 and then calculate the cumulative product
df['Money'] = '$' + df.Percent.where(df.Playing, 1).cumprod().mul(100).astype(str)

df
#Percent  Action  Playing    Money
#0  1.25       1    False   $100.0
#1  1.20       1     True   $120.0
#2  0.50      -1     True    $60.0
#3  0.75       1    False    $60.0
```

Comment: Is `fillna(-1)` necessary, given `NaN != 1`?

Comment: I had pretty much the same thing :) I notice you prefer the fluent interface vs. using operators - e.g. I had `df['Action'].shift() == 1` and `.cumprod() * 100`. Is there a reason other than preferred style?

Comment: @AChampion I found it easier to chain other methods if I use all methods. With operators I need to go back and add parenthesis, which is not a big deal though, makes writing one liner not so much fun :).

Comment: I am getting the entire 'Playing' column as just False.

Comment: What does `df.Action.dtype` say? Is the `Action` column of numeric type?

Comment: Nevermind, my mistake.  I accidentally updated actions to be just -1 and 0.  My bad

Comment: One last question.  How does cumprod() pointed to previous money row?  I guess i dont know how the cumprod is working

Comment: `cumprod` calculates the product of all elements up to the current element. `cumprod([1,2,3,4])` gives `[1,2,6,24]`; The order of `cumprod` and `mul` is exchangable. Because the final result is actually `100 * 1, 100 * 1 * 1.2, 100 * 1 * 1.2 * 0.5, 100 * 1 * 1.2 * 0.5 * 1` so you can calculate cumulative product of the percentage and then multiply with money or multiply percentage with money and then cumulative product, The result should be the same.